# django return and render a csrf_token and variable at the same time for two different forms

Tags: django, render

I have a view in my views.py file which looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('index.html', c), render_to_response('index.html', args)
```

and my index.html looks like this:

```
    <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">User name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

        <input type="submit" value="login" />

    </form>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}

        <input type="submit" value="Register" />

    </form>
```

I want to render c for the form whose action="/accounts/auth/" and render args for the form whose action="/accounts/register/".. any idea how I would go about doing so?

Comment: What makes you think you need two render calls here? Why not just pass both forms in the same dictionary?

Comment: I'm new to django.. would 
return render_to_response('index.html', {c: csrf_token, args: form})
work? I have two csrf_token's though, I tried it and it gave an error saying 'global name 'csrf_token' is not defined'

Comment: Well, except for the fact that you haven't used those names in the template.

Comment: I used {{form}} in the template, so is the return render_to_response('index.html', args: form) part work? How would I merge render_to_response('index.html', args: form) with return render_to_response('index.html', c)? How would I pass both forms in the same dictionary?

Comment: I still don't understand why you think you need two calls. The second argument to render_to_response is a dictionary of all the items you want to pass to the template, where the keys are the names you will use in the template. If you don't understand how to create a dictionary, you should do a Python tutorial.

Comment: Right, but what would my two keys / second argument of render_to_response be in this case? because I have two csrf_token's in the template. I just watched a tutorial which originally made it two different views with two different templates, each form in it'own template, I wanted to just merge the two views so that I can have one template with both forms. I know how to use dictionaries, I just didn't know how to merge two views and use the render_to_response correctly in this case. (im not sure how to render the csrf_token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for two separate csrf tokens, and as your dictionary `c` contains no data other than the token, you can user `render_to_response('index.html', args)` to achieve what you want.

Or even better, use `render(request, 'index.html', args)`. I would also recommend using a template context processor to get the csrf token in your view, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it).

Comment: okay, so i wouldn't need to render c? Because earlier, when the login view was seperate from the registration view, the login view was     c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
return render_to_response('index.html', c)... was the return render_to_response('index.html', c) line useless and did I not need to render c?

Comment: You needed to render c with your separate views because you need the csrf token in your template. But you only need one csrf token in your template, and args already has one. As c has no extra data that needs to be passed to the template, it just supplies duplicate data and can be omitted.